# How to add Cancel Boundary Event in Bizagi Modeller

Tags: bpmn, bizagi

I have a process containing a sub-process. The sub-process can end either normally (with an Untyped End Event) or through Cancel End Event.

In the latter case I wanted to use a Boundary Interrupting Cancel Event to indicate next action taken in such case. I can't find a way to do that though. I can add other types of Boundary Events (both Interrupting and Non-Interrupting), but Cancel is not on the list.

This is a simplification of my process, with Escalation Events used in place of Cancel:

[image: Cancel Boundary Event]

My situation is essentially similar to one described [here](http://tynerblain.com/blog/2006/09/04/bpmn-intermediate-cancel/).

I'm using Bizagi Modeller.

Do I oversee something or is it a limitation of Bizagi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancel Intermediate events can only be stuck to the boundary of a Transaction Sub-Process according to the BPMN standard. It looks like you have used a reusable Sub-Process in your model. You have to right-click on the sub-process shape and select "Is transaction". Afterwards you can right-click on it again and attach the cancel event.

[image]

You will notice that the Transaction Sub-Process has a double lined boundary.

[image: final process with cancel event]